# Making the first word I type on terminal of different color from the others

Tags: command-line, bash

New here. I was trying to make the first word I type on the terminal of a different color from the others. I have looked into the `.bashrc` file and `/etc/inputrc` files. I know that I can make use of the GNU `readline` library to achieve what I want, because it helps in processing the text while the text is being typed, as suggested in the answers to [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/205360/how-does-bash-auto-completion-work). I however, do not wish to mess with the `/etc/inputrc` and `.bashrc` files without being sure it would work.

Comment: This will get you there https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50260269/why-this-bash-function-for-coloring-text-prints-only-first-word-of-whole-string :)

Comment: @Rinzwind that did not sort my issue :( As a side note, earlier when I was trying to removing my username and system name from start in terminal, I did `export PS1="\e[33;1m\W\$\e[;0;m"; clear;` . So following this and your comment I modified this line to, `export PS1="\e[33;1m\W\$\e[40;0;34m$1\e[;0;m";clear;` but it didn't work as expected